# Android Newsreader Example - No Bin Folder

Tags: android, command-line, binary

I am learning to develop for Android devices.

However, when I download the example from:

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

There is no bin folder.  I am developing from the command line (as opposed to through Eclipse), and

```
ant debug install
```

requires a bin folder.

What step am I missing to generate the bin?

Comment: Which Android SDK version are you using? latest is r16.

Comment: Android SDK starts using bin folder since r14, check out the [changelog](http://tools.android.com/recent/buildchangesinrevision14).

Comment: I don't understand - is the example incompatible with r16 then?